# PHP DateTime::createFromFormat return unexpected result

Tags: php, datetime

The code below keep returning 2018/03/02 instead of 2018/02/28
and I really don't know why.

`var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('Y 年 m 月', "2018 年 02 月"));`

Can you explains to me why it return result like that, and is there any work around for it.

Thank you

Comment: Where is the day number supposed to come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> without explicitely providing the day portion will have the current
>   day

Current day is 30 which takes by default if you not provide, which not present in February so it incremented by 2 days which tends to next month march.

If you want last date of current month put `01` as date and use like this

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y 年 m 月 d', "2018 年 02 月 01");
var_dump($date->format("Y-m-t"));
?>
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/944564)

If you are getting value in variable then just add `01` string at last

```
$myDate = "2018 年 02 月";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y 年 m 月 d', $myDate." 01");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a day :

```
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('Y 年 m 月 d', "2018 年 02 月 01"));
// 2018-02-01
```

Comment: your code should work, but in our logic context, it's will very strange if i add day for it

Comment: @ĐạtMèo What's you logic context ? I don't understand `年` nor `月`.

Comment: @ĐạtMèo And it seems like PHP either.

Comment: 年,月 mean year and month accordingly, I have a select box that user can select only year and month, not day level. And one of my user complained why he choosed  February but March results was displayed instead. I changed may code to smt like this `DateTime::createFromFormat(FORMAT_DISPLAY_MONTH_DAY.'-d', $sess['month'].'-01');` but i don'r know it`s a good ideal

Comment: @ĐạtMèo So, where comes from "28" in "2018/02/28" ?